# Change alpha of child view and not the parent view in swift

Tags: swift

Change alpha of child view and not the parent view in swift. I tried this

```
         for v in view.subviews {
                     let view = v
                     view.layer.cornerRadius = 20
                     view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
                     view.alpha = 0.8
                     }
```

[image]

Comment: What's your question? What exactly is your issue with the code you posted?

Comment: I want to change alpha of child views not parent views. See the hierarchy of views

Comment: OK, that's what you want to do. Again, what is your question? What issue are you having with the code you posted? The code you posted changes the `alpha` of all of the child view and not `view` itself.

Comment: It changes the alpha of all the views and subviews. I only want to change the alpha of subviews not the views

Comment: A subview is a view. Be more specific. Which views exactly do you wish to change? The picture you posted shows the view controller's view and its four subviews. Your code sets the alpha of just the four subviews. So which views exactly do you wish to change?

Comment: Yes. But it also hides the image in my hierarchy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m assuming that each of view’s subviews also has subviews, otherwise, like @rmaddy, I’m not sure what the issue is. To drill down to the second layer of subviews, use a nested loop:

```
for v in view.subviews {
    v.subviews.forEach({
        $0.alpha = 0.8
        //etc
    })
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your question, you want set transparency of your four subviews but not affect its subviews (subviews of subviews).

By setting view `alpha` property, all the subviews will be affected and the transparency will be applied to all of then (recursively). If you don't wanna this behavior, set some color with transparency on `backgroundColor` property and keep `alpha` property value `1`.

Otherwise, if you just don't wanna hide the image view, set alpha manually on storyboard instead this loop, or create an imageView outlet and set its alpha to 1 after the loop.